# Как получить фотографию с вебкамеры

Tags: java, web-camera, screenshots

Я ищу библиотеку, что бы вебкамера сделала фотографию и отправила по http. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Получение кадра с камеры может быть сделано, например, через OpenCV. Отправка по http - curl. Наверняка есть привязки их к Java.

Comment: javacv - для вебкамеры, примеры на гитхабе. А для http берите любую популярную библиотеку, коих навалом, например okhttp